# Do you know how to create rows like that? (see picture)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Do you know how to create rows like that?

[image: cells]

Comment: Which specific parts of these cells are you looking to replicate? The delete knobs, the move handles, or the rounded corners, or all of them?

Comment: I'm looking for a delete knobs and move handles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete knobs and move handles are provided by the Cocoa Touch framework, given that you specify in your code that you can edit the table, move cells or delete cells. See the properties of the *UITableView*, *UITableViewDataSource* and the *UITableViewDelegate*. Using these framework features you can ensure that the user can access the move and delete features. Cocoa Touch will handle all the user interface for you! :D

Comment: I've done it! That's work great, but I don't understand why just first item in my table without UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete.

Comment: Cool cool. Glad to help. :) For your first item, check that you're indexing from 0 and not 1 when you specify if they cell can be deleted? There will be some reason why this cell is being treated differently to other cells, so try and look for the difference.

Comment: When I scroll down and scroll up first item becomes like other items, but when I at first load my view it is bad :(

Comment: This is because the cell is being refreshed when you scroll it off and back onto the screen, so the state is being refreshed correctly when it comes back. For some reason the state isn't being updated properly (like the other cells) when you first switch to edit/delete mode.

Comment: I've written my code above how I create a table. What do I wrong?

Comment: Calling the `setEditing:` method within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not the intended use. You need to read some more about UITableView's because I can see you're a bit confused. There's plenty of good documentation/iOS books that cover these things really well.

Answer (score -1):

we can make by custom cell or we can use commiteditingstyle  u can use both methods and make these type of row.